# Android Emulator always throws Exception when relaunching application

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, nullreferenceexception

I created a simple Android application and it runs properly on Android Emulator.
However, when I modify something (adding a variable for instance) and press Run, it sends the apk file to the emulator and it says "Unfortunately MyApplication has stopped working" then restarts it and it works perfectly.
I checked the log and it has nothing to do with my application, it complains about some NullException in the APK loader. I restarted the emulator and the Eclipse, too, I use the latest SDK to build my app, my Min API level is 8, target is 16.

I do not use native code.

I paste the error log here:

```
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4124)
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:377)
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:320)
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:493)
02-14 12:55:43.541: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Do you share user id with other package by using sharedUserId attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I do not see any _sharedUserId_ attribute. My application is consisting of 5 activities and when I use "Back" to the main activity, it doesn't crash. However, when I use Run while being in an inner activity, the exception is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to kill the application before you launch it again. I don't know of any other way to do it. You can't have two of the same process running at the same time. My guess is that the very time it works nice, but second time, it doesn't.

You can mayhaps run another instance of the emulator, but that is NOT recommended.

Comment: But why the _Eclipse_ doesn't send a KILL signal if the _Eclipse_ sends another instance of the application? And how can I kill it?

Comment: You can simply kill the application from inside Android (usally under settings) or just quit the application with the back or homebutton. Make sure you dont have any active activities under the same time.

I think you can compare it with a program that is running and occupying some ports on internet or something, if the port is occupied, it would be quit strange if eclipse just closed the port, he has no idea who is using it. So killing something, that it doesnt know what it is isnt that smart.

Comment: I would assume that Eclipse knows something about the application that sends to the emulator. Some sort of callback or returned process id or anything. Well, I think I'm just used to my experiences of developing .Net with Visual Studio. Comparing it to Android development is like cutting trees with an axe compared to using an industrial saw. Lightyears, unfortunately... :(

Comment: Yes, going from an IDE to another is sometimes very frustrating, did my answer help you?

Comment: Your answer just points out that my problem is valid, though I mark it. My opinion is still the same, the IDE lacks many essential functions.